# expressj : Cant render headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, response

I am working on the simple login form and after login(successfully), i wish to render a list of products. But the login form itself does not get rendered. Here is what i have in `app.js`

```
app.get ( '/users/new', routes.api.user.isLogged, routes.api.user.new );
```

the `isLogged` method only tells whether the session exist or not. There seems to be no problem there.

In my `user.js` file, in the new method, this is what i have got :

```
  exports.new = function(req, res) {
    res.format({
      html: function() {
        return res.render('users/new', {title: 'Login'});
      }
    });
  };
```

Sometimes, it renders without hesitation and sometimes it cracks up an error saying

```
domain.js:66
    throw er;
          ^
Error: Can't render headers after they are sent to the client.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage._renderHeaders (http.js:715:11)
    at ServerResponse.res._renderHeaders (/Users/kaushik/dev/my_repos/retailer-catalog-backend/node_modules/kue/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:76:25)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (http.js:1083:20)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (http.js:1040:8)
    at ServerResponse.module.exports.res.write (/Users/kaushik/dev/my_repos/retailer-catalog-backend/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/compress.js:79:34)
    at ondata (stream.js:38:26)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at ReadStream._emitData (fs.js:1368:10)
    at afterRead (fs.js:1350:10)
    at Object.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:362:17)
```

I don't really understand why this happens. I am new to express and node.

**EDIT**

`isLogged` method has :

```
 exports.isLogged = function(req, res, next) {  
   if (req.session.user) {
     res.redirect('/' + req.session.user.username + '/retailers')
   } else{
     return next();
   };
 };
```

this is the `app.js` server configuration:

```
  app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'hbs'); 
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.compress());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/routes/web/public' }));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: '5234523451' })); 
    app.use(validator);
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'routes', 'web', 'public')));
  });
```

Comment: just curious, why not just do res.render('users/new') by itself instead of res.format? Not sure what that does.

Comment: @chovy it's used for content negotiation (like when the client tells the server it would prefer JSON responses), but you are right, since there's only one response here (HTML), `res.format()` is superfluous. @ktkaushik your posted code seems okay, could you post more? Esp. your middleware setup (`app.use(...)`) and `isLogged`.

Comment: @chovy i wish to add `json` response as well. But thats not coming as of now.

Comment: @robertklep i have added the isLogged and my app configurations. Sorry about the indentation. I try, but it does show up the way i want it :(

Comment: try to remove `return next();` in `exports.isLogged..` and just call `next();` without returning it ..

Comment: @GeoPhoenix nope.. that did not help. As of now, i am testing on Google Chrome, Safari and Google Chrome Canary. It works perfectly fine on Canary but it throws error on Safari and Chrome.

Comment: @ktkaushik could it be related to `validator`? And just to be sure, if you remove the `isLogged` middleware, do the errors still occur?

Comment: @robertklep yes, even after i removed the validator. The error seems to persist. Just to be sure i printed out something in the console inside the `res.format({html: function(){ console.log('print this') }})` and it did print.

Comment: @ktkaushik how are you using `kue`?

Comment: `kue` is not really used in this module. I haven't implemented that part myself. Is is something that could be bothering or interfering here ? Is there a different server command that i should run in parallel ? cos i am not doing any of it except `nodemon app.js`

Comment: Okay, so it was working on `Canary` unless i `shift + reload` it. That is when even `canary` browser is showing the same errors